# When Printing an Array, It Prints out Garbage Characters as well

Tags: arrays, c

What I'm trying to do is first input a number which will determine how many characters I want to input (Ex. n = 4), then the user will input the characters they want (Ex. line = abcd). Then they can specify what order the characters will go in (Ex. Input: 4 3 2 1 and Output: dcba).

```c
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n); fgetc(stdin);
    char characters[n + 1];
    fgets(characters, n + 1, stdin);

    char orderedChars[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int index;
        scanf("%d", &index);
        orderedChars[i] = characters[index - 1];
    }

    printf("%s", orderedChars);
}
```

But when I try to print out the array, it prints out `dcba▄■a` instead of just `dcba`, but when I keep adding 1 to `n`, one Unicode character goes away until 7+ where it doesn't become a problem. (Simple representation)

```
n = 5
Char's: abcde
Order: 5 4 3 2 1
Output: edcba■a

n = 6
Char's: abcdef
Order: 6 5 4 3 2 1
Output: fedcbaa

n = 7 
Char's: abcdefg
Order: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Output: gfedcba
```

The first four lines seem to be correct but I don't know if it could also be something to do with the code inside the for-loop or maybe something to do with `scanf` or how I printed out the array.

Comment: It doesn't print unicode character, it just prints garbage

Comment: Are you aware that `index` can have a range of `UINT_MIN`-`UINT_MAX`? The array `characters[]` is probably not always large enough and you will get UB. You can also get negative values for `index`, in which cause you will have UB when `characters[]` is an array and not just a pointer to the middle of an array with enough previous elements.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ah, ok so that's what that's called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`orderedChars` is uninitialized and its initial value is indeterminate.

`%s` in `printf()` requires the passed buffer null-terminated.

Add terminating null-character to avoid troubles.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n); fgetc(stdin);
    char characters[n + 1];
    fgets(characters, n + 1, stdin);

    char orderedChars[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int index;
        scanf("%d", &index);
        orderedChars[i] = characters[index - 1];
    }
    orderedChars[n] = '\0'; /* add this */

    printf("%s", orderedChars);
}
```

Another option is to tell `printf()` the length to print.
You don't have to allocate for terminating null-character in this case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n); fgetc(stdin);
    char characters[n + 1];
    fgets(characters, n + 1, stdin);

    char orderedChars[n]; /* only n elements are required instead of n + 1 */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int index;
        scanf("%d", &index);
        orderedChars[i] = characters[index - 1];
    }

    printf("%.*s", n, orderedChars); /* add .* to the format and add the length n */
}
```